# How do I reset the Buffalo AirStation HighPower N600 Gigabit Dual Band Wireless Router WZR-600DHP to factory settings?

Tags: router, wireless-router

This is quite a stupid question; I apologize in advance.  I was trying to configure my [Buffalo WZR-600DHP](http://www.amazon.ca/Buffalo-AirStation-HighPower-Wireless-WZR-600DHP/dp/B0096239G0/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1384374468&sr=8-1&keywords=buffalo+router) to connect to a VPN and send all traffic through it.  I've managed to completely screw up the routing table, so I want to reset the unit back to factory settings.  Unfortunately, I can't for the life of me find the reset button.  As I am visually impaired, the diagrams in the manual, if any, do not help me.  Can someone please describe the location of the reset button on this type of router?  I've spent all morning trying various buttons and places that look like pin-hole reset buttons, and just haven't had any luck.  This is incredibly embarrassing!

Comment: Those models have the option to firmware-default via web interface. Is it not possible for you to gain web access? Nor telnet or SSH? Even if routing table is screwed, the routr should have any IP address, so you could find it using something like "netdiscover" (Linux).

Comment: Unfortunately, whenever I connect to the router, it tries to send the traffic for 192.168.11.1 through the VPN now, so obviously accessing the administration interface fails.  But I'll try taking off the support stand after lunch; thanks for that idea!

Comment: The accepted answer is correct. Once the stand is off, the button is easy to find. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had just the same problem with my Buffalo WHR-HP-GN (very similar to your model).
After a long time searching for it, the reset button was behind the support foot, the stand that makes the router remain in vertical position.
In my model removing this stand was not easy, and I finally broke a bit the piece. Good luck for your attempt.

Comment: My model may differ slightly but I noticed there is actually a small hole directly in the center of the support foot allowing you to reset the router without removing the stand. ymmv.